# Request Payload data in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Was just trying to sync a model in Sencha Touch and realised that it doesn't yet support sending of Nested Model data. So I'm having to do the Ajax request manually.

How can I send the data via 'Request Payload' instead of parameters etc?

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: '/api/blah',
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
            request: toAdd,
        },
        success: function(response, opts) {

        },
        failure: function(response, opts) {

        }
    });
```

I'm guessing it has to be a particular header I send across?

Thanks, Dominic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/api/blah',
    method: 'POST',
    jsonData: {
        //the object data etc,
    },
    success: function(response, opts) {

    },
    failure: function(response, opts) {

    }
});
```