# Ext.ajax.request can not use 0 in jsonData

Tags: ajax, sencha-touch

I am implementing an Ext.Ajax.request in a similar manner to the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610684/request-payload-data-in-sencha-touch).  When I include jsonData: 1, this appears in the request payload of the header. With jsonData: 0, nothing appears in the header payload and the server receives no data. What could be the problem?

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/my/url',
    method: 'PUT',
    jsonData: 0, //doesn't work but 1 does
    success: function(response, opts) {

    },
    failure: function(response, opts) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the original Sencha code.

```
    if (jsonData && !Ext.isPrimitive(jsonData)) {
        data = Ext.encode(data);
    }
```

your call will try to send 0 (which could be easily equal to false or not being an object) or 1 (which could be easily equal to true or being an object).

you should definately try to go for a real json if you use this config param.

```
    jsonData: {"value": 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the following works:

```
jsonData: '' + val,
```